# ¿Cómo cambio el color del navbar al pasar por una sección?

Tags: html, jquery, css, web

Hola quisiera saber cómo puedo cambiar el color o agregar una clase al pasar por esa sección específicamente cambie de color al pasar de sección.

Lo he hecho con *jQuery* pero al verlo en otras pantallas no funciona por que se muestra antes o después.

```
$(function (){
     $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1400) {
         $('.negro').addClass("azul");
        } else {
         $(".negro").removeClass("azul");
        }
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es natural que en un sitio web, al cambiar de dispositivo, cambien de lugar algunas cosas de lugar, ya que no todas las pantallas son iguales. Es ahí donde ya no podemos usar un numero fijo en el código y tendremos que hacer todo más dinámico:

```
$(function (){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > $("#seccion").offset().top) {
            $('.negro').addClass("azul");
        } else {
            $(".negro").removeClass("azul");
        }
    });
});
```

Fijate en el método `$("#seccion").offset().top`, aquí obtenemos ese punto en donde quieres hacer el cambio, y es dinámico ya que entrega un valor distinto dependiendo de la posición del elemento en la pantalla.

Comment: muchisimas gracias amigo

Comment: Si te funcionó, recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta! Gracias!